# android : not able to add geofence from service

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am not able to add geofence from service class. Below is my code:

**GeoFenceService:**

```
package com.example.admin.reminderapp.services;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.admin.reminderapp.R;
import com.example.admin.reminderapp.database.model.Reminder;
import com.example.admin.reminderapp.geofencing.Constants;
import com.example.admin.reminderapp.geofencing.GeofenceErrorMessages;
import com.example.admin.reminderapp.geofencing.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GeoFenceService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Context mContext = this;

    private IBinder mIBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public GeoFenceService() {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "GeoFenceService()");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mIBinder;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i("GeoFenceService", "buildGoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("GeoFenceService", "onCreate");
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i("GeoFenceService", "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.e("GeoFenceService", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i("GeoFenceService", "Connection suspended");
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest(long reminderId) {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(populateGeofenceList(reminderId));
        return builder.build();
    }

    public List<Geofence> populateGeofenceList(long reminderId) {
        List<Geofence> geofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        Reminder reminder = Reminder.load(Reminder.class, reminderId);

        Log.i("ReminderService", reminder.getId()+" - "+reminder.toString());

        Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(String.valueOf(reminderId))
                .setCircularRegion(
                        reminder.getLat(),
                        reminder.getLat(),
                        (float) reminder.getKm() * 1000
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();
        geofenceList.add(geofence);
        return geofenceList;
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent(long reminderId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        Log.i("ReminderService", intent +"");
//        intent.putExtra("ReminderId", reminderId);
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public void addGeofence(long reminderId) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(reminderId),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent(reminderId)
            ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                mContext,
                                "Reminder Added.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                    } else {
                        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(GeoFenceService.this, status.getStatusCode());
                        Log.e(GeoFenceService.this.getClass().getName(), errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Invalid location permission. You need to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with geofences");
            securityException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeGeofence(long reminderId) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencePendingIntent(reminderId)
            ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                mContext,
                                "Reminder Removed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                    } else {
                        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(GeoFenceService.this,
                                status.getStatusCode());
                        Log.e(GeoFenceService.this.getClass().getName(), errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Invalid location permission. You need to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with geofences");
            securityException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public GeoFenceService getService() {
            return GeoFenceService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

**GeoFenceTransitionIntentService:**

```
package com.example.admin.reminderapp.geofencing;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.admin.reminderapp.R;
import com.example.admin.reminderapp.activity.HomeActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p/>
 * TODO: Customize class - update intent actions, extra parameters and static
 * helper methods.
 */
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";
    Boolean isMessageTone, isMessageVibrate;
    String messageTone;

    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
        Log.i(TAG, "GeofenceTransitionsIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
//        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
//        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
//            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
//                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
//            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
//            return;
//        }
//
//        // Get the transition type.
//        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
//
//        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
//        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
//                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
//
//            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
//            // multiple geofences.
//            List triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
//
//            // Get the transition details as a String.
//            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
//                    this,
//                    geofenceTransition,
//                    triggeringGeofences
//            );
//
//            // Send notification and log the transition details.
//            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
//            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
//        } else {
//            // Log the error.
//            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
//                    geofenceTransition));
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent");

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));
        }
    }

    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
            Context context,
            int geofenceTransition,
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);
        ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {

        int notifyColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("NotificationPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        isMessageTone = prefs.getBoolean("is_message_notification", false);
        isMessageVibrate = prefs.getBoolean("is_message_vibrate", false);
        messageTone = prefs.getString("message_notificationTone", "");

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Theme", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
        if (storedPreference == 0 || storedPreference == 1) {
            notifyColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);
        } else if (storedPreference == 2) {
            notifyColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_theme2);
        } else if (storedPreference == 3) {
            notifyColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_theme3);
        } else if (storedPreference == 4) {
            notifyColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_theme4);
        } else if (storedPreference == 5) {
            notifyColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_theme5);
        }

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_directions_black)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_directions_black))
                .setColor(notifyColor)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        if (isMessageTone) {
            if (messageTone.equals("")) {
                Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                builder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
            } else {
                builder.setSound(Uri.parse(messageTone));
            }
            if (isMessageVibrate) {
                builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000});
            }
        }

        builder.setAutoCancel(true);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:

I am able to get the toast "Geofence added". But when I am selecting my current location for fencing, its not triggering any notification. Before when I used to do this from activity, it use to trigger the notification if my device location is in fencing which I have added.

Please help me to find the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please share the code for registering geofence ?

Comment: @HirenPatel Hi hirenbhai.. I have code for adding geofence..it lies in GeoFenceService.. method is addGeofence..

Comment: I think what @HirenPatel was trying to point out is that we can't find where you call your `addGeofence(long reminderId)` method.  That seems to be the reason why you aren't getting your toast notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this way:

I have created `GeoFenceObserversationService` **singleton** class.

**GeoFenceObserversationService.java**:

```
public class GeoFenceObserversationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

    protected static final String TAG = "GeoFenceObserversationService";
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    private boolean mGeofencesAdded;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private static GeoFenceObserversationService mInstant;
    public static GeoFenceObserversationService getInstant(){
        return mInstant;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstant = this;
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mGeofencesAdded = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(AppConstants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, false);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    protected void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {

        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }


    public void addGeofences() {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

        populateGeofenceList();
        if(!mGeofenceList.isEmpty()){
            try {
                LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
            } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
                securityException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        }

    public void removeGeofences() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient,getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            securityException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void onResult(Status status) {

        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            mGeofencesAdded = !mGeofencesAdded;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(AppConstants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, mGeofencesAdded);
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = AppConstants.getErrorString(this,status.getStatusCode());
            Log.i("Geofence", errorMessage);
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private void populateGeofenceList() {
        mGeofenceList.clear();
        List<GeoFencingResponce> geoFenceList = getGeofencesList;
        if(geoFenceList!=null&&!geoFenceList.isEmpty()){
            for (GeoFencingResponce obj : geoFenceList){
                mGeofenceList.add(obj.getGeofence());
                Log.i(TAG,"Registered Geofences : " + obj.Id+"-"+obj.Name+"-"+obj.Lattitude+"-"+obj.Longitude);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AppConstant**:

```
   public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = PACKAGE_NAME + ".SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME";
    public static final String GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME + ".GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY";
    public static final String DETECTED_GEOFENCES = "detected_geofences";
    public static final String DETECTED_BEACONS = "detected_beacons";

    public static String getErrorString(Context context, int errorCode) {
        Resources mResources = context.getResources();
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.geofence_not_available);
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.geofence_too_many_geofences);
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.geofence_too_many_pending_intents);
            default:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_error);
        }
    }
```

Where I started Service ? From Application class

- `startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GeoFenceObserversationService.class));`

How I registered Geofences ?

- `GeoFenceObserversationService.getInstant().addGeofences();`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @ChintanSoni, Glad to help you. :)