# How to start intent service when app is killed or destroyed?

Tags: android, kill-process, android-geofence

I am try to solve this issue by Creating This Code Which is Shown Below. But I am not getting Result. can Anyone help to answer this Question?

-In Geofence Triggering Transition notification not getting while killed the app.
-Entry Exit Notification Works Properly When app is in Background but After kill the application notification not working Properly.

```
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if(GpsService.mTimer != null)
    {
        startService(new Intent(context, GpsService.class));
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
```

Comment: Not sure how it would work since the context is being destroyed. try to use  `getApplicationContext()` instead

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973536/android-not-able-to-add-geofence-from-service/35979567#35979567, it works fine for me

Comment: "while killed the app" what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

From your service's onStartCommand(), return START_STICKY. In that case (ideally) the service will restart even when the app is "killed".

(If START_STICKY works, no need to start service from onDestroy. Android will take care of it).

However, in some manufacturer's phone, if you clear the app from Recent Task list, it "Force Kills" the app. In that case the service will not restart and you can't do much.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onDestroy()
 {
     super.onDestroy();
     if(GpsService.mTimer != null)
     {
         startService(new Intent(context, GpsService.class));
     }
     Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
 }
```

This will first destroy your activity and then your condition will be checked . Which is useless thing .You can try this

```
  public void onDestroy()
      {
          if(GpsService.mTimer != null)
          {
              startService(new Intent(context, GpsService.class));
          }
          Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
               super.onDestroy();

      }
```

`